# Gwt compiled version missing elements

Tags: gwt

I followed the instructions at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html#compiling to compile and then open my html file GenChessDb.html. But its missing all the elements created using Java (javascript after being compiled).

From what I understand about gwt, all of that should have run from the following line in my html file.

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="genchessdb/genchessdb.nocache.js"></script>`

I'm guessing something went wrong with the execution of the script. The debug mode (hosted mode) runs just fine. How do I debug what is going wrong with production mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put the files on a webserver?

Because I got the same "error" when I compiled them and tried to open the HTML file under windows. For some reasons the JavaScript isn't executed then.

Try putting them into e.g. the standard IE working dreictory or start an apache tomcat server.

Hope this helps!